# Query function in python

Tags: python-3.x

This is how my dataframe looks like:

```
    videoId   textOriginal 
0    A          hello
1    B          I am confused
```

I am trying to using query function in python. I want the function to return videoId for corresponding textOriginal.

This is what I have written so far:

```
ans = ['I am confused']  #list returned from another function
data.query('textOriginal == "ans[0]"')['videoId']
```

which returns

```
Series([], Name: videoId, dtype: object)
```

But I want it to return something like this:

```
data.query('textOriginal == "I am confused"')['videoId']
1    B
Name: videoId, dtype: object
```

Comment: When you write `'textOriginal == "ans[0]"'`, you produce a string with the literal contents `textOriginal == "ans[0]"`.  Perhaps you want `'textOriginal == ' + ans[0]`.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean?